# Make a sprite move left or right in p5.play.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my sprite be able to move left or right. It can jump, but not move. I have tried different approaches, but I'm clearly missing something.
I'm using p5.js and its addon p5.play.js.
Here's my code:

```
p5.prototype.print = p5.prototype.println;

var asterisk;
var platform;

var GRAVITY = 1;
var JUMP = 15;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 600);

    asterisk = createSprite(30, 200, 20, 60);

  //if defined, the collider will be used for mouse events
  asterisk.setCollider("circle", 0,0,33);

  platform = createSprite(200, 585, 500, 20);
}

function draw() {

    background(51);

    asterisk.velocity.y += GRAVITY;

  if(asterisk.collide(platform)) {
    asterisk.velocity.y = 0;
  }

  if(keyWentDown("UP_ARROW") || mouseWentDown(LEFT)){
    asterisk.velocity.y = -JUMP;
  }

    function keyReleased() {
        if (key != ' '){
            asterisk.setDir(0);
        }
    }

    function keyPressed(){
        if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW){
            asterisk.setDir(1);
        }else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
            asterisk.setDir(-1);
        }
    }

    drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: You should change asterisk.velocity.x, not fox

Comment: I believe you have to change both fox.direction (so the character is facing the right direction) and asterisk.velocity.x like @Bálint sugested.

Comment: @Bálint Wow, sorry about that. Changing between projects and making snippets ready for Stack goes too quick sometimes. Have changed what you suggested. Still, nothing is happening when using the arrow keys. I have also edited the Snippet above with your suggested changes.